# Windows universal 10 async freezes program

Tags: c#, async-await, win-universal-app

i want to get an BitmapImage with the ReadBufferAsync method from FileIO. The method i want to call is an async method that awaits another async method.

```
public class A
{
    public static async Task<StorageFile> getFile(string fileName)
    {
        StorageFolder myfolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        return await myfolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
    }

    public static async Task<BitmapImage> getImage(string fileName)
    {
        StorageFile file = getFile(fileName).Result;
        var image = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);
        return new BitmapImage(new Uri(file.Path));
    }
}
```

in an other class i call
BitmapImage f = A.getImage("123.png").Result;

However my program freezes when awaiting myfolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
I presume this is caused because it doesn't go back to the GUI thread. If this is the case how can easily go to the GUI thread an go back to this method?

Is there an easy way to solve this problem?

I tried using Task.Run and the Factory

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
{ 
     //code
});
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in an other class I call `BitmapImage f = A.getImage("123.png").Result;`

This is the point at which the UI is likely frozen.

Asking for the result of a task waits for the task to complete. Nothing else happens while you are waiting; that includes updating the UI. If that's not what you want, don't ask for the result; `await` the result: `BitmapImage f = await A.getImage("123.png");`.  That means "resume at this point when the image is available; keep processing the UI updates while we're waiting."

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are getting the result of each task using the `Result` property. According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Accessing the property's get accessor blocks the calling thread until the asynchronous operation is complete; it is equivalent to calling the Wait method.

To fix this (or get the result asynchronously) you should `await` the result:

```
public static async Task<BitmapImage> getImage(string fileName)
{
    StorageFile file = await getFile(fileName);
    var image = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);
    return new BitmapImage(new Uri(file.Path));
}
```

and in that other class you tell us about, you should have:

```
BitmapImage f = await A.getImage("123.png");
```